# WebApi/.net-core: Can't access to webapi

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core, postman

I cant access to webapi from postman

the error is the next:

[image]

As you see no authoritation.

valuescontroller.cs is:

```
namespace CVService.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]

    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs is:

```
namespace CVService
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

startup.cs is:

```
namespace CVService
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it was a problem of Cors and I added the library but same problem.

the command I use is dotnet run from terminal, I am using SDK version 2.1.301.

**dotnet --info**

```
SDK de .NET Core (reflejando cualquier global.json):
 Version:   2.1.301
 Commit:    59524873d6

Entorno de tiempo de ejecución:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.16299
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.301\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.1
  Commit:  6985b9f684

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Why can't I access? what is wrong?

Comment: You are calling the wrong URL. `api/Values/Get` does not exists according to the attributes used. just  call `api/values`. The comments in the code example actually show you what path to call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why can't I access? what is wrong?

You are calling the wrong URL.

```
GET api/values/get
```

does not exist according to the attributes used.

Call

```
GET api/values
```

The comments in the code example actually show you what paths are available to call based on the actions in the controller

```
// GET api/values
// GET api/values/5
// POST api/values
// PUT api/values/5
// DELETE api/values/5
```

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: ok from Postmant was activated SSL certificate verification, I disabled it.

Comment: I had the same issue and @David is right. Disable SSL certificate validation on Postman but remember to re-enable SSL certificate verification after testing the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Three steps to solve this issue:

1. Inside of your `Startup.cs` file's `Configure` method, add this code:

   ```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
     {
         endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
             name: "default",
             pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
     });
   ```
2. Change your controller's route like this:

   ```
      [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
   ```
3. It's better to add to your action constructor a pattern like `[FromQuery]`; than you can call your API like this:

   ```
          api/Values/Get?id=5
   ```